# generate session for users after registering?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using drupal-6, developing a custom module, and after using:
user_save(null, $user_array);

I want that user to be logged in?

I used sess_regenerate(), but isn't getting the user logged in? what is the way to solve this, and thanks.

my code:

```
$user_array = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'pass' => $pass,
    'mail' => $email,
    'status' => 1,
    'init' => $email,
);           
user_save(null, $user_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread. That may help you!
http://drupal.org/node/1363710

Comment: Yes I just tried this, still isn't getting he user logged in, I tried this:

global $user;
$user= user_load($user_array);

it's weird, I also tried:

user_authenticate($user_array); 

and still not working, I guess I'm doing something wrong!